# Font Identification Wedding Stationary on Amazon

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to identify and purchase a font from an Amazon wedding stationary product. I have used What The Font and other font identification engines, and can not find it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am looking at the "fourteen" font in the picture, the "head" font looks like a different font than the rest of the number cards.

[https://www.amazon.com/Crisky-Wedding-Anniversary-Birthday-Double-Sided/dp/B09F2YG84T/ref=sr_1_17](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09F2YG84T)

[image: what font is this]

Comment: Does it have to be exactly the same, or is close good enough?  Adobe has a font called Storybook which is quite close. [see example](https://imgur.com/a/HyzzjWB).

Comment: Using a [trimmed and adjusted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyuPT.png) ... [whatthefont.com](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/whatthefont?step=resultPage) found **many** very close matches. Are you certain you searched well? Just use the image I linked to here and use WhatTheFont.. you'll find many possibilities.

Comment: @BillyKerr thank you that is a great option!